# How to check Variable type?

Tags: solidity

Is there any solidity function that can return the type of the variable passed to it? I know I can find out the variable type by reading the code, but I just wonder if there is such a function.

Comment: Why do you want to check not from the code? I don't understand

Comment: Already answered https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/6918/43618